# Where is Sera in Skyhold?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

After leaving Skyhold and wandering around a bit, it seems that my companions all moved into different places than before. I've found most of them again, but I'm having some real trouble finding Sera. She used to be in the courtyard, but now she's nowhere to be seen.

Where exactly can I find her?

Comment: You know you can use the map, and important characters like companions are marked there, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sera moves to a small room/balcony on the first floor of the Herald's Rest Tavern, next to where Cassandra, Iron Bull and the scout are standing.